# AllNodesFailedException: Could not reach any contact point

Tags: java, docker, cassandra

I have set three Cassandra Nodes (cas1, cas2 and cas3) in three datacenter (DC1,DC2 and DC3) through docker. I want to establish a session at cas1 using Java API but it fails to connect and throws the exception.

I have tried setting up port manually and looking solutions available but they didn't work.

cas1 creation :

```
docker run --name cas1 -p 19041:9042 -e CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=MyCluster -e CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH=GossipingPropertyFileSnitch -e CASSANDRA_DC=DC1 -e CASSANDRA_RACK=RAC1 -d cassandra
```

Java Code :

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("172.17.0.2");
InetSocketAddress addrSoc = new InetSocketAddress(addr,19041);
CqlSession session = CqlSession.builder().addContactPoint(addrSoc).build();
```

Expected result : Session should have been established.

Error :

datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1, use getErrors() for more: com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.metadata.DefaultNode@605c5ab0(null,/172.17.0.2:19041): com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] init query STARTUP: error writing )

Comment: is cassandra process started inside the docker?

Comment: Yes it is inside the docker.

Comment: is the telnet working from your java api server/container to cassandra nodes?

Comment: How do I check that?

Answer (score 3):

Faced the same issue. Resolved by changing the node ip(172.18.0.2) to global ip '127.0.0.1' in the configuration class.

I used docker-compose command to run cassandra. Please see my dockr-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
 n1:
  build: .
  image: cassandra-with-cqlshrc
  networks:
   - cluster
  ports:
   - "9042:9042"
networks:
 cluster:
```

My CassandraConfiguration file in java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories
public class CassandraConfiguration extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    @Override
      public String getContactPoints() {
        return "127.0.0.1";
      }

      @Override
      protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return "stockmarket";
      }
     
      @Override
      protected int getPort() {
          return 9042;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It worked. I used the IP : 127.0.0.1 instead of the global IP and the port 19041 (that I configured explicitly) and it managed to connect.

Answer (score 1):

All DataStax drivers are moving from built-in DataCenter failover and local inference from contact points. ([source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19779#issuecomment-575619392))

If you are with Spring/Springboot, **you have to specify data center name**. Add this line to your application.properties:
`spring.data.cassandra.local-datacenter=datacenter1`

With the name of your datacenter, 'datacenter1' is the default one. You can find datacenter's name with this command in cqlsh: `select data_center from system.local;`

Also, **don't forget to close the cqlsh session**, because it can cause some problems with reaching single-node cassandra cluster in next requests.

`Session.close()`

Comment: @AlexOtt, I've experienced the same problem, and the solution was to close the sessions. Maybe the JVM was stuck because of that, so as I though it was related, I shared my answer/experience.